# How to build a window frame with hand tools?

Tags: joinery

I'm interested in the process of building a traditional 1920s America window frame with only hand tools and was wondering if someone could explain the basic process by which the pieces are cut, joined, and styled (moulding plane?). Are there any good classic books on this kind of joinery?  Would especially be interested in materials from that era or earlier.  Thanks, and let me know if I can provide any more detail.

Comment: *Exclusively* with hand tools?

Comment: Yes, that would be preferred. Assuming I'm buying wood already rough cut at a lumber yard or home store. Thank you.

Comment: If you watch [the woodwright s shop](http://www.pbs.org/show/woodwrights-shop/) show or better yet in-roll in [The Woodwright School](http://www.woodwrightschool.com/) , you will learn how to work with hand tools, you will even learn how to make your own hand tools to use to make your window frame. Do a web search for the Woodwright's shop and you will find books and dvds to purchase that will give the knowledge you seek.

Comment: From what I gather from The Woodwright's Shop (Roy Underhill had at least 2 episodes involving windows) and other sources, sash making was cream of the crop work - all of the stock has to be precisely straight and square in all directions, and the joinery has to be spot on with little room for error.

Comment: on the plus side, you get to use the enigmatic "sash filetster" ;-)

Comment: @neongreensticker given we have not had much response thus far, it would be helpful to reduce the scope and/or split this into multiple questions (perhaps one about materials, another about the joinery you have seen in such windows, tools required for specific operations, etc.). What have you found in your research thus far, and do you have some examples you can share that illustrate the look you want to achieve?

Comment: take a look at https://lostartpress.com/collections/books/products/doormaking-and-window-making This is a lovingly create reprint of exactly what you are looking for. "That joiner wrote two short illustrated booklets that explained how to build doors and windows by hand. ...
Plenty of books exist on building windows and doors, but most of them assume you have had a seven-year apprenticeship and don’t need to know the basic skills of the house joiner. Or the doors and windows these books describe are impossibly complex or ornamental."